# c++: program calling constructor of another class and I don't know why

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have the following code:

IMPORTANT: it's not necessary to immediately get what it is doing, it's more of a general C++ question (new to it)

```
class xINT
{

private:
    int num;
    static int countCtor;
    static int countDtor;
    static int countCopycon;
    static int countOpAssign;

public:
    xINT()
    {
        std::cout << this << ": " << "ctor" << std::endl;
        ++countCtor;
    }

    ~xINT()
    {
        std::cout << this << ": " << "dtor" << std::endl;
        ++countDtor;
    }

    xINT(const xINT& x)
    {
        std::cout << this << ": " << "copycon of " << std::dec << &x << std::endl;
        num = x.getNum();
        ++countCopycon;
    }

    xINT& operator=(const xINT& x)
    {
        if (&x == this)
        {
            std::cout << "op=" << std::endl;
            //return *this; 
        }

        std::cout << this << ": " << "op= of " << std::dec << &x << std::endl;
        num = x.getNum();
        ++countOpAssign;
        return *this;
    }

    int getNum() const { return num; }
    void setNum(int val) { num = val; }
    static void statistik(std::ostream&);
    static void reset();
};

class A
{
public:
    A(xINT i)
    { i_ = i;
    } 
private:
    xINT i_;
};

int main()
{
    
    xINT i;
    cout << &i << endl;
    i.setNum(42);
    {
        std::cout << "Class A:" << std::endl;
        A a(i);
    }
}
```

...and now my question: if while debugging the code gets to the line where the object of type A a(i); is defined the first thing the program does is jumping into the constructor xINT(const xINT& x) of class xINT. Why is that?

THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE!!

I would have expected it to simply create an object of type A (with all the obvious operations coming with it). Also, the last thing the program does before the object A a(i) is fully created is to jump into xINT& operator=(const xINT& x). Are these some special kind of constructors which are called if an object of type xINT is passed in a method or operated with?

Comment: Replace the `A` constructor with `A(xINT const& i) : i_(i) {}` and you will see very different results.

Comment: In order to make an `A` object you have to first make the `xINT` object that is part of `A`, so the `xINT` constructor is called. Your code could be improved like this `A(xINT i) : i_(i) {}` but that just changes which `xINT` constructor is called not the fact that an `xINT` constructor has to be called.

Comment: *'Are these some special kind of constructors which are called if an object of type xINT is passed in a method or operated with?'* If you pass an object **by value** then it's copy constructor will be called. If you want to avoid that then pass by reference (preferably by const reference). And then there's the possibility of moving instead of copying, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for A take an XInt by copy, not by reference. So the constructor needs to recreate the object with the copy constructor (which is what you are seeing being called).

Even if you passed it by reference, you are setting the local i in A equal to it, so the copy constructor would be called there.

Comment: @273K It needs to create 1 copy, but this doesn't mean you need one additional copy to pass as the parameter. It's 2 object creations when passing by reference vs 3 object creations + 1 copy assignment when passing by value.

Answer (score 1):

Since the constructor signature is `A::A(xINT)`, i.e. you pass the object by value, the `xINT` object passed to the constructor is a copy of `i`. This means the copy constructor of `xINT` gets called before any logic of `A`'s constructor runs.

As next step before entering the body of the constructor all initializers for non-static member variables of `A` are run. This means the default constructor of `xINT` gets executed.

Inside the body of `A::A` the only thing that happens is the call to the copy assignment operator of `xINT`. (expression `i_ = i;`).

Then the constructor exits and the object that was created as constructor parameter gets destroyed...

You may want to rewrite the constructor as

```
A(xINT const& i)
   : i_(i)
{
}
```

This would result in only a call to the copy constructor of `xINT` to construct the member variable of `A` without creating an additional `xINT` object.

Comment: I definitely already get it better now, thanks.

What part of the copy constructor makes it "know" that it is to be called? For me at first glance it looked like it needs to be an object of type xINT with another xINT being passed to the constructor e.g. xINT example(i) with i being an xINT. Why is it still called?

Comment: @AZYZ Yes that's a pretty good summary of when the copy constructor is called. What makes you think that explanation is wrong? Maybe you don't understand that parameters need constructing as well? The parameter `i` of `A::A(xINT i)` needs to be constructed, and that is done with the copy constructor (in this case).